# Checking is there any same type object inside of the object list?

Tags: c#, list, object, types, equality

I have an object list which is derived from A type (X and Y derived from A)

```
List<A> list = new List<A>()
{
   new X(),
   new Y(),
};
```

I have an object which is derived from A type. Z object

I want to check type equality that if there is same type with Z object inside of the list object types
How can i write like this code?

Comment: So X,Y,Z are derived from A? and u wanna check if a Z object is inside that list of A?

Comment: Is the type Z fixed at compile time or shall it be determined dynamically at runtime?

Comment: And one more question: does the type have to match exactly or are derived types OK? Example: if the list contains an object of type ZZ which is derived from Z, will it be a match or not?

Comment: @KlausGütter it  can be determine at runtime. By the way my object types does not support any interfaces, like IEnumerable etc..

Comment: @KlausGütter my does the type have to match exactly-->yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply write as the suggested duplicate:

```
bool containsOfTypeZ = list.OfType<Z>().Any();
```

Or as thought by @KlausGütter:

```
var someType = someInstance.GetType();
bool containsOfSomeRuntimeType = list.Any(o => o.GetType() == someType);
```

Comment: `FirstOrDefault() != null` can be simplified to `Any()`

Comment: No need to use a where or an instance of the type Z, you can simply, use a linq like this list.Any(x => x.GetType() == typeof(Z));

Comment: Or `list.Any(a => a is Z)`, which will help if you need to find anything that's *derived* from `Z` too.

Comment: By the way my object types does not support any interfaces, like IEnumerable etc

Comment: @thepasserby No matters... We act on the `List<>` instance. `Z` can be any `class` type, even `struct` and `enum` or `delegate`, etc. Thus Linq extension methods act on `IEnumerable<Z>`.